# Forming a foundation in PHP

Tags: programming, web-development, databases

Does anyone know what topics I should start studying to form a foundation in PHP ? Loops, outputting data, manipulating a database etc. ?

Edit: I want to start using PHP to create a social site. Something like Instagram, TikTok etc.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [cseducators.se]! Right now your question is a bit broad and hard to give a specific answer to. You mention more basic things like looping and outputting data in addition to more complicated things like using a database. Could you provide some more details about what you'd like to use PHP for / what your motivation for learning it is?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Ok I edited my question

Comment: Thanks for adding that information! Honestly I think the best advice I can give you is to start with the basics of HTML and CSS. I that it's really easy to motivate yourself to work on that stuff because of the immediate visual feedback as you work. You could also start to learn backend web development if that's more interesting!

Comment: Ok thanks. I already know how to output things, how to insert, select, delete and update things in the database, the different loops etc. I was just wondering if there was anything else on the basics side I needed to cover before moving on

Comment: If you're not already familiar, I'd get to know how HTML/CSS work and definitely try to understand how HTTP works and the distinction between back end and front end.